# Using at to run a .txt file or command with flags

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks

I need to run (in bash) a .txt file containing a bunch of commands written to it by another program, at a specific time using at. Normally I would run this with `bash myfile.txt` but of I choose to run `at bash myfile.txt midnight` it doesn't like it, saying

```
syntax error. Last token seen: b
Garbled time
```

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
echo 'bash myfile.txt' | at midnight
```

[at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)) reads commands from standard input or a specified file (parameter `-f filename`); not from the command line.

Comment: Oops, that was obvious :P Thanks very much, I should've seen that.